# GravityForms v2.5 custom field mask - escaping a "9"

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This question is intended to update this previous question: [Gravity forms custom field mask - escaping a "9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655179/gravity-forms-custom-field-mask-escaping-a-9).

I would like to add a custom field mask with a "+39" as start of the string, but 9s are intepretated as placeholder.

I've tried using backslash before it, using quote marks and double quotes, but nothing solved the issue.

Comment: It seems your question is answered by my answer on the question you linked to.

Comment: @DavefromGravityWiz it is not working for me, i guess that's why now there is a new sisstem for masking?

Comment: Dang, you're absolutely right. I updated my answer with a stop-gap solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673241/227711